# Solve using Riccati equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In this problem, they've asked to solve it using the solution $y=-\frac{1}{3x}$ but the problem is that the solution just makes it more complicated.

The equation which needs to be solved is, $y'+6y^2 = \frac{1}{x^2} $

Using the solution as $y=z+\frac{1}{3x}$ then after substitution and simplification I end up with $z'+6z^2+\frac{4z}{x}=\frac{2}{3x^2}$ and then further simplified using $V=\frac{1}{z}$

which ended up with $v'-\frac{4v}{x}=6+\frac{2v^2}{3x^2}$ regardless how I chose the integrating factor it just complicates the issue.

Can someone help me out please?

Edit: The problem is solved. The issue was with the solution given.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote this correctly? Using $y$, if you substitute into the ODE, the LHS should equal the RHS.

Comment: Probably meant $y = -\frac1{3x}$ (or $y=\frac1{2x}$), not $y = \frac1{3x}$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies it does seem like it. My bad. How did you determine the value which has to be used for y? Like $y=-\frac{1}{3x}$ or $y=\frac{1}{2x}$

Comment: I guessed that the intended function was of the form $a/x$
but the wrong value $a=1/3$ was caused by a typographical error.
There should still be infinitely many further solutions
besides the two special solutions $y = -\frac1{3x}$ and $y=\frac1{2x}$
obtained by guessing $y=a/x$.
$$ $$
P.S. Apropos of typographical errors, the name is Riccati with two c's,
not Ricati.

Comment: @Tharindu: So, is the question now answered or is going to be corrected/updated? Regards

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Yeah that was the issue. I guess determining the factor depends on guess work and then applying it to the function to see it fits, right?

Comment: @Amzoti Yes the problem is solved, I updated it.